# debug error run time check failure #2 stack around the variable was corrupted

Tags: c

I'm making a count the digits of numbers with C language. I'm using visual studio 2019. But if I run this program, it gets an error message "run time check failure #2 stack around the variable was corrupted".
How can I solve this problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    long int n;
    int count = 0;

    printf("Enter an integer: ");
    scanf_s("%lld", &n);


    while (n != 0) {
        n /= 10;
        ++count;
    }

    printf("Number of digits: %d", count);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `%lld` is not matching `long int`. It is is for `long long int`.

Comment: Try changing `%lld` to `%ld` to match the type?

Comment: Yes, I missed the basic thing. Thank you for your answer.